# APK Icon Not Showing Upon Installation

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-tv

I'm installing an apk onto my system and it runs fine via adb shell using :

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.example/.MainActivity
```

However, no icon displays on the screen to manually select. I'm wondering if this is an option to select when I build my apk. When I install apk other than my own, their icon does show. I install using:

```
adb install -r app-release.apk
```

Below is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.opengl">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<!-- Tell the system this app requires OpenGL ES  -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00030000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:banner="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Snapshot"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What does your manifest look like? How are you installing the apk?

Comment: I've attached my AndroidManifest.xml ;;;

Install via:
adb connect <ADDRESS>
adb devices
#ensure connection
adb install -r app-release.apk
adb shell
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.example/.MainActivity

Comment: Hm. Is this on a device or an emulator? Does it behave the same on other emulators? Also, what happens if you delete the `android:icon` attribute from the `.MainActivity` activity tag?

Comment: I'm using both a physical device and emulator and it behaves the same in both. No change if I remove that attribute - which I believe was a remnant when I began the project with the default tv format.

Comment: what launcher app are you using? also why are you using `android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER` instead of `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`

Comment: Whatever is default through Android Studio 2.1.3. Is there way to specifically check? I'm using leanback because it was the default - should I change it?

Comment: *Leanback launcher* is a launcher for Android TV. Are you developing for Android TV?

Comment: yes, I'm developing for TV

Answer (score 0):

The drawable you put for the "android:banner" attribute is what shows on the home screen of an Android TV. Can you try moving it from the Activity declaration in your manifest to the `Application` declaration in your manifest?

`android:banner="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"`

That has been working for me.

Comment: Changed to the following & still not working :[  ::::  

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:banner="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">

Comment: I also tried the following : Go to File > New > Image Assets > select launcher icon > choose image file. But when I confirm everything, it still doesn't display on screen like other apks do.

Comment: Could it be where it installs? It installs within : /data/local/tmp/

Comment: I'm having the same issue